# ¿Se pueden utilizar una biblioteca DLL en PHP?

Tags: php, c#, iis

Buenas noches, quisiera saber si se puede ejecutar una DLL en PHP.

Como en c# en el *codebing* se le agrega una referencia.

Quisiera saber si se puede implementar y utilizar, y también si se puede publicar PHP en el iis.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Hola claro que se puede de hecho microsoft permite desde hace varios años te dejo esta información en cuanto a IIS en Windows server . https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh994590(v=ws.11).aspx

Según la documentación de PHP

**He compilado un DLL para calcular algo. ¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutar ese DLL bajo PHP?**
Si se trata de un DLL simple no hay forma aun de ejecutarlo desde PHP. Si el archivo DLL contiene un servidor COM es posible que pueda acceder a él si implementa la interfaz IDispatch.

He trabajado con COM en C# y debes generarlo a la interfaz de tu .dll . Usar COM  va de acuerdo al lenguaje que uses para generar .dll compilado.

Si no sabes que es COM aquí te dejo informacióm http://www.conocimientosweb.net/dcmt/ficha13441.html

**Ejemplo de uso con PHP y Visual Basic**

Fuente: [http://www.elguille.info/colabora/2009/antoniobarbado_convertidor_rtf_txt_php.htm]

Si usas PHP en servidores windows, existe la posibilidad de usar objetos COM. Actualmente .NET tiene la capacidad de poder generar interoperabilidad COM en las DLL (Librerias de clases) que se generan con Visual Studio. En realidad lo que genera no es una DLL COM "nativa" que se pueda registrar con el comando regsvr32 como otras, sino que gracias a un wrapper COM de .NET expone este ensamblado (DLL) como si de un objeto COM se tratara.

Para ello, me pasé horas buscando información por internet y al final decidí crearme mi propio convertidor usando la propia librería de clases de .NET

**Paso 1. Creamos nuestra DLL.**

o primero fué crearme mi DLL, para ello cree un nuevo proyecto de libreria de clases. Elimine la clase que te genera por defecto y añadí un nuevo elemento llamado Clase COM (COM class).

Una vez hecho esto, el propio Visual Studio te genera los identificadores necesarios para que tu clase sea un clase COM válida, p.e que tenga un constructor sin parametros para que servidor lo pueda instanciar y sus identificadores necesarios.

Ya solo nos falta añadir la funcionalidad deseada a nuestra dll, en mi caso que nos convierta rtf a txt usando como "convertidor" el richtextbox.  Aquí pego el código.

```
    <ComClass(Rtf2txt.ClassId, Rtf2txt.InterfaceId, Rtf2txt.EventsId)> _
    Public Class Rtf2txt

    #Region "GUID de COM"
        ' Estos GUID proporcionan la identidad de COM para esta clase 
        ' y las interfaces de COM. Si las cambia, los clientes 
        ' existentes no podrán obtener acceso a la clase.
        Public Const ClassId As String = "6bb5e369-448b-45e1-a157-a754d6232484"
        Public Const InterfaceId As String = "cf05e0fc-28c4-4a16-a355-a772d21bfd81"
        Public Const EventsId As String = "05502bdc-5212-485c-b566-16a35ed40e2f"
    #End Region

        ' Una clase COM que se puede crear debe tener Public Sub New() 
        ' sin parámetros, si no la clase no se 
        ' registrará en el registro COM y no se podrá crear a 
        ' través de CreateObject.
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub

        Public Function Convertir(ByVal strCampoRtf As String) As String

            Dim c As New System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox()
            Dim s As String = String.Empty

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(entrada) Then
                Try
                    c.Rtf = strCampoRtf
                    s = c.Text
                Catch ex As Exception
                    s = strCampoRtf
                End Try
            End If

            Return s
    End Function

 End Class
```

**Nota:**
Este código necesita que agregueis una referencia al System.Windows.Forms que es la que contiene la clase RitchTextBox

**Compilación de la librería y registrar interoperabilidad COM**

Ahora debemos activar "Registrar para Interoperabilidad COM" en el apartado "Compilar" de las propiedades del proyecto, aunque no estoy muy seguro de que al añadir una clase COM ya Visual Studio lo activa por nosotros.. pero por si acaso, le echamos un vistazo y listo.

Si generamos el proyecto, Visual Studio nos genera la dll y nos la instala en COM automaticamente con lo que si tenemos nuestro servidor web con PHP en la misma máquina podemos usar la interfaz COM de nuestra dll de forma instantánea.

Para ello usariamos, por ejemplo desde PHP

```
$p = new COM("Convertidor.Rtf2txt");
echo $p->Convertir("PEPE");
```

Donde Convertidor es el nombre del proyecto y Rtf2txt el nombre de la clase dentro de mi proyecto. Así mismo si posteriormente añadimos mas funciones útiles las usaríamos como Convertidor.<>

**Registro de la DLL en otro servidor**
Aquí es donde viene lo bueno y donde mas me dolió la cabeza, ya que aquí tuve que averiguar como hacerlo al no tener el Visual Studio que lo hacía por mí.

En primer lugar, debemos registrar la dll en el equipo que queramos que use dicha librería. Por supuesto, que dicho equipo debe tener el .NET Framework que hayamos usado para generar nuestra dll, en mi caso el 2.0

Para registrar la dll, copiamos la dll de nuestro directorio Release o Debug, y movemos la dll a un sitio en el PATH del equipo y ejecutamos la herramienta regasm (que está disponible en la ruta donde se instala el .Net Framework), usando /tbl para que genere la libreria de tipos y /codebase para que incluya el path seleccionado de la dll ya que no está en la caché de ensamblados.

```
    C:\> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe C:\php5\Convertidor.dll
    /tlb:C:\Php5 Convertidor.tlb /codebase

    Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 2.0.50727.1433
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004.  All rights reserved.

    Types registered successfully
    Assembly exported to 'C:\Php5\Convertidor.tlb', and the type library was registered successfully

    C:\>
```

Una vez hecho esto, generará un mensaje como este y si es así ya tenemos disponible la dll para usarla desde el servidor Web con PHP y COM.

Nota:
Si probais la dll, y despues quereis sustituirla porque la habeis actualizado, recordad reiniciar el servidor web para que la libere y así podais sobrescribirla, sino os dará error de acceso denegado por archivo en uso.

Para el caso que nos ocupa, tened cuidado con el texto que se le pasa al campo Rtf, sino es código Rtf (osea con sus {\rtf1 etc..}) dará error de formato no válido.

**NOTA:**
Ahora debido a que COM es muy limitado al sistema operativo te recomiendo crees un servicio web donde uses la .dll y creas métodos con lo que necesitas y desde php solo lo consumes esa seria la mejor manera e incluso mas sencilla por si un dia te toque usar Linux como S.O de tu servidor

Comment: ¿Podrías aportar un ejemplo de uso de DLL en php?

Comment: Mira encontré esto.[http://superahacker.blogspot.com/2009/07/usando-dlls-de-visual-basic-6-en-php.html] Ahora debido a que COM es muy limitado al sistema operativo  te recomiendo crees un servicio web donde uses la .dll y creas métodos con lo que necesitas y desde php solo lo consumes esa seria la mejor manera e incluso mas sencilla por si un dia te toque usar Linux como S.O de tu servidor.

Comment: Los enlaces tienen el inconveniente de que pueden dejar de funcionar, y tu respuesta quedaría incompleta, puedes añadirlo a respuesta?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu recomendación acabo de editar la respuesta.

Comment: @edwin hermano tu crees que me puedes ayudar por skype

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar como esta en la documentación oficial que dice:

El objeto devuelto es un objeto sobrecargado, lo que significa que PHP no ve ningún método fijo como lo hace con las clases regulares; en su lugar, los accesos a cualquier propiedad o método se pasan a COM y de allí a DOTNET. En otras palabras, el objeto .Net se mapea a través de la capa de interoperabilidad COM proporcionada por el tiempo de ejecución .Net.

Una vez que haya creado un objeto DOTNET, PHP lo trata de manera idéntica a cualquier otro objeto COM; todas las mismas reglas se aplican.

```
  <?php
  $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Collections.Stack");
  $stack->Push(".Net");
  $stack->Push("Hello ");
  echo $stack->Pop() . $stack->Pop();
  ?>
```

Este seria ya un ejemplo ya datos lo tome de la documentación oficial y lo que hace es crear un excel

```
<?php
$full_assembly_string = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=14.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c';
$full_class_name = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass';

$e = new DOTNET($full_assembly_string, $full_class_name);
$wb = $e->workbooks->add();
$Precios = $wb->Worksheets(1);
$Precios->Name = 'Precios';
$Venta = $wb->Worksheets(2);
$Venta->Name = 'Venta';
$Tons = $wb->Worksheets(3);
$Tons->Name = 'Tons';

 $Meses = Array('2014-01', '2014-02', '2014-03', '2014-04', '2014-05', 
 '2014-06', '2014-07', '2014-08', '2014-09', '2014-10', '2014-11',   
 '2014-12');

 foreach ($Meses as $Numero => $Mes) {
 $Precios->Range("A" . ($Numero+1))->Value = $Mes;
 }

 $wb->SaveAs('c:\temp\Meta.2014.05.xlsx');
 $wb->Close();

 ?>
```

Si quiere ver otros ejemplos te dejo el [link](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php)

Comment: disculpa @Raul Cacacho , me podrías explicar que es `mscorlib` ? y `System.Collections.Stack`? como explicarías este código?

Comment: mscorlib es Constructor de clase `DOTNET` especifica qué ensamblaje debe cargarse, y class_name especifica qué clase de ese ensamblado crear.  Esto segun la documentación de `php DOTNET`

Comment: @Sebastián Lagos Yañez System.Collections.Stack es el nombre de la clase de la aplicación de office que quieres abrir modifique la respuesta con un ejemplo para q se ve más claro