# ejecutar dll en php wamp

Tags: php

Me han dado una dll que lo que hace es encriptar un usuario/clave o lo que le ponga (Desconozco cómo funciona la dll).
Cómo hago desde PHP para poder llamar a esa dll y poder encriptar el valor de una variable por ejemplo?

Código de ejemplo:

```
try    {
  $dll = new COM('mi_dll.clase'); 
  $dll->Function(); 
  } catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage(), "\n";}
```

Recibo este error:

```
error: Failed to create COM object `mi_dll.class': Sintaxis no v�lida
```

EDIT:

Me han pasado este pedazo de código en .net, pero sigo sin dar en la tecla en PHP

```
mi_dll.Desencriptar casillaSmtp = new mi_dll.Desencriptar();
smtp = casillaSmtp.DecryptString(smtpEncriptado);
```

Comment: Tal vez esta información te puede ayudar [¿Se pueden utilizar una biblioteca DLL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130011/se-pueden-utilizar-una-biblioteca-dll-en-php), Saludos.

Comment: @VickMuñoz gracias por la info. Por el momento no logré llamar a la dll

Answer (score 0):

para poder utilizar una libreria externa en PHP (se denominan extensiones), debes configurarlo en el archivo `php.ini`, en el apartado extension.
Existe un directorio a definir, donde se dejara el archivo .dll, y luego se solicitara su carga.

```
extension_dir="/usr/bin/php/ext/"

extension=libreria.dll
```

espero te sirva esta info.

Comment: Ok, agregué la dll en el php.ini. Aún así sigo obteniendo el mismo mensaje de error

Comment: reiniciaste servidor (usas XAMP, WAMP) ?

Comment: Uso wamp. Lo reinicié, y aún sigo con el mismo inconveniente

Comment: Puedes mandar un pantalla del php.ini modificado?

Comment: Lo otro, armate un archivo PHP de prueba, que tenga solo la instruccion phpinfo() para ver si carga la extensión, o da un error al iniciar, porque puede ser la forma de instanciar la funcionalidad

Comment: agregué la dll en la ruta C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.32\ext y en el .ini coloqué extension=mi_dll.dll --- Del phpinfo, qué cosa debería aparecer?

Comment: agregaste también en php.ini la ruta de las extensiones (extension_dir=C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.32\ext)? si hiciste un php con la funcion phpinfo() debe salir si pudo o no cargar la librería. Googlea phpinfo y mira las imagenes (no se como agregar imagines acá en Stack), veras que sale todo lo necesario para determinar si están cargándose las configuraciones necesarias para tu ambiente, en especifico la libreria que quieras utilizar

Comment: no logro visualizar las dll en el php.ini. En el .ini sí agregué la ruta con las extensiones

Comment: He conseguido añadir la dll finalmente, pero sigo sin poder adaptar el código de visual studio en php

Comment: consulta, ya te sale en la información que te indica la funcion "phpinfo()" ?

Comment: otra cosa, que ahora me salta como inquietud: ¿La DLL esta construida para ser utilizada por PHP?  No todas las librerias sirven para ser utilizadas en PHP.

Comment: no aparece en phpinfo(), pero sí aparece en las opciones de wamp "PHP extensions" y la dll tildada. La dll no fue construida específicamente para php.